# Good practices for Data Scientists that work in R and engineers who work in Java and C++ collaborating

Tags: java, c++, r, code-generation

My company has a production application being built in Java and C++. We have recently added Data Scientists who are skilled at and using R. I am wondering what best practices people have for making sure that work done in R is best leveraged. For instance is our best option to call R code from Java or C++? I have located http://www.renjin.org/about.html.

Or is there a good way to convert code from R to Java or C++?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a big fan of Renjin as its Java-based interpreter will only cover a subset of CRAN, and at that the subset that does *not* involve calls to C++.

I am a bigger fan of either

- separation of concern:

  - use something like [Rserve](https://rforge.net/Rserve/) for headless connection from anything (including Java), or
  - use something like [OpenCPU](http://opencpu.org) to turn *everything* into web-based access
- for heavier-duty work, interface C++ directly via [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) which well over 400 CRAN packages do.

Comment: Too bad Dirk ;-) We are fans of Rcpp. You're right-- currently Renjin chokes on compiling C++ code, but not for long! We use GCC as a front end for our native code compiler, so we have just a few steps left to get C++ code compiling properly to JVM byte code.

Comment: I would obviously welcome that as a fairly significant (and dare I say, growing) portion of CRAN relies on that language.